# which methods spark join depends on to finish the join

Tags: apache-spark

I wanna write myself's Key class of JavaPairRDD and implement myself's join logic. So do I need to rewrite the equals() and hashCode() methods of the key class please, or by rewriting others.
For example:
You know JavaPairRDD.join(JavaPairRDD) very straightforward, just when the StringKey1.equals(StringKey2) would be matched.
But for me, I hope even if the key1 just key2's substring also be matched. So I think I have to write a wrap class to tell Spark as long as they are matching my logic you should treat them as a same key, and join them. for example "ab" should be joined with "abc".

Comment: I tried rewrite the equals method, but it didn't work.

Comment: Huh....can you please explain your problem a little fuller? Sometimes this can even lead to you solving the problem...

Comment: Thanks Justin, I modified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override both `equals` and `hashCode`. HOWEVER, you will need to attempt to explicitly cast your `other` object as pattern matching does not work. I am still trying to figure out why the match fails on type alone (I am guessing serialization). Also keep in mind that if the key objects are truly not matching, then one will override the other in the final output...which might not be what you want.

```
case class Foo(x: String) {
  override def equals(other: Any) = { 
    Option(other).map(_.asInstanceOf[Foo]).getOrElse(null)
    match 
    {
      case f : Foo => 
        x contains(f.x)
      case _ => false
    }
  }

  override def hashCode() = 1
}

sc.parallelize(List((Foo("abcdefg"),1))).join(sc.parallelize(List((Foo("abcdef"),1)))).collect
```

Comment: Thank you so much Justin, I appreciate the detailed example code. I also added hashCode() method, it works now! But I don't understand why the "Join Operation" needs two methods to identify the same Key, is only equals() not enough? Actually hashCode did nothing either. Why scala/spark design this rule?

Comment: @Jack I think it's important to mention that a solution that always returns the same `hashCode` effectively removes all chances of parallelizing the computation across nodes. `hashcode` is used to assign a given key to a partition. `hashCode() = 1` will use a single node, so what would be the point of using Spark? Use a local solution instead.

Comment: @maag That really makes sense, please see my comments below for your kind post.

Answer (score 1):

Hacking the semantics of `equals` and `hashCode` to force spark to join on things that are not equal is a bad idea.

Spark relies on the key's `hashCode` to partition data on the cluster. Forcing an constant hashCode will force data to go to a single partition, removing the possibility of distributing the computation on a cluster. This implies that the computation can be/should be done in one node, probably using proper single-node techniques.

This problem can be addressed using Spark, by taking a different approach:

```
val data1 = List("abcd" -> 4, "defghy" -> 6 , "wxxyyy" -> 3, "az" -> 24)
val data2 = List("ab" -> 2, "fghz" -> 3 , "y" -> 1, "a" -> 2)

val base = sparkContext.parallelize(data1)
val jn = sparkContext.parallelize(data2)

val cartesian = base.cartesian(jn)

val joined = cartesian.collect{case ((k1,v1),(k2,v2)) if (k1.contains(k2)) => (k1,(v1,v2))}

joined.collect
```

This results in:

```
res6: Array[(String, (Int, Int))] = Array((abcd,(4,2)), (defghy,(6,1)), (wxxyyy,(3,1)), (az,(24,2)))
```

Comment: Hey Gerard, That's awesome! Thank you very very much! I like your solution very much! and I've put it on my code. Thanks again! -Jack

Comment: btw, does the cartesian have a little bit performance issue, since it's MxN connections.

Comment: @Jack it is intrinsically a m x n problem unless we can restrict it somehow. For example, if instead of substring,  we could say 'startsWith' then we could first join on the 1st  character.